# Android, How can I make AVD smaller?

Tags: android, screen, android-virtual-device

I have created an AVD with the following characteristics:
Target: Android Honeycomb (API level Honeycomb)
SD card size: 64M
Skin: Built-in WXVGA

But the problem is, when I run this ADV, size of it is more bigger than screen size of my laptop. Therefore, I don't have access to all screen of the AVD.

What should I do to make it smaller?

Comment: you can use HVGA mode instead of WXVGA. It will be smaller when compared to WXVGA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From within Eclipse:

```
1) Go to Window -> Android SDK and AVD Manager -> Virtual Devices
2) Select the AVD you want to launch and click Start
3) Check the "Scale display to real size" button
```

Answer (score 4):

While launching the Emualator, just mention the **`screen size(in)`** inside the **`"Scale display to real size"`**. You can mention the size in inch overthere.

Just look at below image. You can find out this **launch options** by first selecting AVD Name from AVD Manager and then click on start button.

[image].